# How can I keep track of two lists in a function (fold) in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml, fold

The goal of my this code is two split one list into two lists based on a simple condition and I'm having trouble doing this in just one function.

Currently, I fold over the list passed in and say if the condition is true, add to list one. Then I fold again and say if the condition is false, add to list two. This is horribly inefficient for larger lists and I don't know how to combine it into one fold.

My working, inefficient code currently looks like this:

```
let function test old_list_one original_list =
  let list_one = (fold (fun a elt -> 
      if condition = true then elt::a
        else a) old_list_one original_list) in
  let list_two = (fold (fun a elt -> 
      if condition = false then elt::a
            else a) [] original_list) in
do_something list_one list_two
```

This works for smaller sets but runs out of resources on larger sets. I tried combining the folds like this:

```
let function test old_list_one = 
  let list_two = [] in
  let list_one = (fold (fun a elt -> 
      if (condition) = true then elt::a
        else elt::list_two) old_list_one original) in
do_something list_one list_two
```

OCaml doesn't keep track of list_two and it remains []...how can I can keep track of list_two and list_one in ONE function?

Also, for those unfamiliar with fold - it's a function that iterates over every element in original and accumulates the result to old_list_one (in this example)

Edit: Using a tuple as the accumulator did the trick!

Comment: That's not a "crash", it's a compiler error. BTW, there is a function included in the OCaml StdLib that does just this. `List.partition`.

Comment: Not allowed to use anything except pervasives, thanks for the response though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a pair of lists as your accumulator parameter. The accumulated value can be anything you like.

Here's a sketch of what it might look like:

```
let f (a, b) x =
    let a' = <calculate> in
    let b' = <calculate> in
    (a', b')

let (list1, list2) = List.fold_left f ([],[]) original_list
```

Comment: How would I reaccess the lists inside the list though? So if I was to do `let pair_of_lists = (fold) [solutions;[]] original` and add it to the head of the accumulator if condition is true and tail if it's false, I'm not sure how I could reaccess the pair_of_lists after the fold finishes. I'll updated the question with the code I'm trying so you can see what I mean.